# Why parent class is not able to access child class member

Tags: oop, system-verilog

If we go according to below code

```
class A;
  int a = 10;
endclass

class B extends A;
  int b = 20;
endclass

program test;
  A a1;
  B b1;
  initial begin
    b1 = new();
    a1 = b1; //child class object is assigned to parent class handle
    $display("Value of variable b is %x", a1.b);
  end
endprogram
```

Then the above code results into error that "Could not find member 'b' in class 'A'"
Now my observation is that when extended class object is assigned to base class handle then simulator will check the type of handle and check whether variable is present in that class or not. As variable b is not defined in base class then it will result into error.
So I want to confirm whether my above observation is correct or incorrect?
I would welcome if anyone wants to add something to my observation, in case it's correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use the terms **parent** and **child** class here. It implies you have two separate class *objects*.

What you describe is two different class *types* where one type is derived/extended from a base type. Then you declare two class *variables*: `a1` and `b1`. These variables may hold a *handle* to class object of the same type, or a handle to an object of any type extended the type of the variable. However, the compiler will not let you reference any variable or member that has not been defined by type of the class variable regardless of the type of the object the class variable currently hold a handle to.

OOP gives you the ability to interact with a class variable with the possibility of it having a handle to much more complex object without you knowing what extensions have been made to that object. But you have to assume that the object could be the same type as the class variable. The compiler enforces this as well. If you want to interact with the extended class variables, you need to use an extended class variable type.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, and it is the intended behavior in OOP languages I know (I don't especially know the one you are using, but your example is simple enough). Being able to use a variable declared by a child class would result in a violation of the object oriented principle of [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) (or subtyping).

I will answer you in Java, because I'm sure of the syntax in this language for the example i want to give. Imagine two variables with the same declared type :

```
public A buildA () {
    return new B();
}
public static void main () {
    A a1 = new A();
    A b1 = buildA();
}
```

The polymorphism principle is that `a1` and `b1` should implement the same interface and be used indifferently. If I was allowed to access a variable's member `b`, since the compiler couldn't guess which is base and which is child, then it would allow the program to crash at runtime every time I access a concrete `A`, removing the safety net types are supposed to provide.

Answer (score -1):

yes you are correct. there are basically two types of binding compiler does. early binding and late binding. generally in our code compiler does early binding which means it binds the class variables or methods call to the type of handle and here because of early binding it finds variable b in class A which does not exists so it gives error. late binding can be done when we put virtual keyword before any method and in that case compiler does not bind the property with the type of handle. instead it does late binding i.e. binding with the type of object assigned to it.